# Create UserControl with an ItemSource property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, listbox

I have a `UserControl` that has a `ListBox` as one of its children.  I'd like to be able to define a `ItemsSource` dependency property on the `UserControl` itself when using the control, and have the child `ListBox` use this value as its own `ItemsSource` property.

I defined a dependency property of type `IEnumerable` (I've also tried using `ObservableCollection`) in my `UserControl`'s codebehind, but the binding only seems to apply once - when the source list changes, the `CollectionChanged` notifications don't seem to be propagating through the `UserControl` and to its child `ListBox`.

**How can I define a property on my `UserControl` that will update the `ListBox` as if the `ListBox` wasn't embedded in the `UserControl`?**

Here's a simplified view of my UserControl:

Definition of the `ItemsSource` property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(SidePanelItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

public IEnumerable ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

Attempting to use this property as the `ListBox`'s `ItemSource`:

```
<UserControl x:Name="myControl">
  <.. other elements ..>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=ItemsSource}"/>
  </.. other elements ..>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: That should work, anyways it's an approach I don't like, you'd rather handle this at the ViewModel leve. make sure you pass an `ObservableCollection<T>` to it so that the ListBox updates accordingly.

Comment: [Try this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uj2vxeu1bq5peio/MvvmLight17.rar). It's pretty much your exact same code and it works fine even for updates. Only unknown from your question is as HighCore stated the input type from the VM to your `UserControl`'s `ItemSource` property. If that's not actually notifying changes done on itself, the changes ain't going to get propagated to the `ListBox`.